# Error Install OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, opencv

Trying to install OpenCV 3.1.0 on Raspbian Pi-2, came up with this error.

> Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_ts.a
>   [ 52%] Built target opencv_ts
>   Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Can't find the specific issue.

Comment: Have you seen this http://answers.opencv.org/question/65086/opencv-2411-failed-to-build/

Comment: Yeah, tried that one. No change.

Comment: I've tried a few things - setting ffmpeg path, switching to 3.0.0. Ends up failing at different %'s with the same "Makefile:147:recipe for target 'all' failed to make"

Answer (score 1):

Use a 2A, 5V Adapter, and in the make process type `sudo make -j3` instead of `-j4`. In some cases, the RasPi cannot handle using all the processor cores.

Regarding the use of the mentioned adapter, the peripherals are hungry for current. The Pi is short-circuit protected, when it can't get enough current for all the peripherals, it automatically shuts down. so use a 2A, 5V adapter to prevent the Pi from shutting down automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok its so simple. 2 things first.

1) Are you compiling with Contrib package?

2) Did you allocate process to execute the make command like make -j *#number* ?

If 1, then some of the contrib packages are legacy, so try to compile the package that you need alone.

If 2, So simple please don't allocate any process for make command. Because due to dependencies make command will fail. So just compile with make command alone like $ make